# I need 2% code coverage. What to put in my test class?

Tags: unit-test

The code won't get to this line.

```
else
    {
        htmlCode = 'Sorry, there seems to be an issue generating this report. Please contact the project manager.';
    }
```

This is the test class

```
@isTest 
public class vf_BOG_Executive_Report_Test {

    @testSetup static void test_DataSetup() 
    {

        Id acctRTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType='Account' AND Name='FIGS Federation Account' LIMIT 1].ID;
        Id contactRTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType='Contact' AND Name='Contact' LIMIT 1].ID;
        Id bmRTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType='BOG_Membership__c' AND Name='New BOG System' LIMIT 1].ID;

        List<Account> acctList = new List<Account>();
        List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();

        Account a1 = new Account(Name='AccountTest1',RecordTypeId=acctRTypeId); 
        Account a2 = new Account(Name='AccountTest2',RecordTypeId=acctRTypeId);  
        Account a3 = new Account(Name='AccountTest3',RecordTypeId=acctRTypeId);    
        acctList.add(a1);
        acctList.add(a2);
        acctList.add(a3);
        insert acctList;

        Contact c1 = new Contact(FirstName='firstName',LastName='ContactTest1',RecordTypeId=contactRTypeId,Constituent_Code__c='Donor',AccountId=acctList[0].id);
        Contact c2 = new Contact(FirstName='firstName',LastName='ContactTest2',RecordTypeId=contactRTypeId,Constituent_Code__c='Donor',AccountId=acctList[1].id); 
        Contact c3 = new Contact(FirstName='firstName',LastName='ContactTest3',RecordTypeId=contactRTypeId,Constituent_Code__c='Donor',AccountId=acctList[2].id);  
        contactList.add(c1);
        contactList.add(c2);
        contactList.add(c3);
        insert contactList;


        BOG_Membership__c bm = new BOG_Membership__c(Contact__c=c1.id, RecordTypeId=bmRTypeId, Date_To__c =date.today(),BOG_Membership_Type_New__c = 'Member',Org__c='WZO');
        BOG_Membership__c bm5 = new BOG_Membership__c(Contact__c=c2.id, RecordTypeId=bmRTypeId, Date_To__c =date.today(),BOG_Membership_Type_New__c = 'Member',Org__c='WZO');        
        BOG_Membership__c bm4 = new BOG_Membership__c(Contact__c=contactList[0].id, RecordTypeId=bmRTypeId, Date_To__c =date.today(),BOG_Membership_Type_New__c = 'Member',Org__c='None');        
        BOG_Membership__c bm2 = new BOG_Membership__c(Contact__c=contactList[0].id, RecordTypeId=bmRTypeId, Date_To__c =date.today(),BOG_Membership_Type_New__c = 'Invitee');
        BOG_Membership__c bm3 = new BOG_Membership__c(Contact__c=c3.id, RecordTypeId=bmRTypeId, Date_To__c =date.today(),BOG_Membership_Type_New__c = 'Staff');        

        // Insert 
        insert bm;
        insert bm2; 
        insert bm3;         
        insert bm4;        
        insert bm5;                

        BOG_Committee__c bc = new BOG_Committee__c(Name='1 The Executive',Official_1__c=c1.id,Role_1__c='Chair',Official_2__c=c2.id,Role_2__c='Chair');
        BOG_Committee__c bc2 = new BOG_Committee__c(Name='1 The Executive',Official_1__c=c3.id,Role_1__c='Chair');
        insert bc;
        insert bc2;

        BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c bcm = new BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c (BOG_Committee__c=bc.id,BOG_Membership__c=bm.id,Executive_Membership_Type__c = 'Member',Start_Date__c=date.today());
        BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c bcm2 = new BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c (BOG_Committee__c=bc2.id,BOG_Membership__c=bm5.id,Executive_Membership_Type__c = 'Member',Start_Date__c=date.today());
        BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c bcm3 = new BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c (BOG_Committee__c=bc.id,BOG_Membership__c=bm3.id,Executive_Membership_Type__c = 'Member',Start_Date__c=date.today());            
        BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c bcm4 = new BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c (BOG_Committee__c=bc.id,BOG_Membership__c=bm2.id,Executive_Membership_Type__c = 'Staff',Start_Date__c=date.today());
        BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c bcm5 = new BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c (BOG_Committee__c=bc.id,BOG_Membership__c=bm4.id,Executive_Membership_Type__c = 'Invitee',Start_Date__c=date.today());

        insert bcm;
        insert bcm2;
        insert bcm3;            
        insert bcm4;            
        insert bcm5; 

    }

    static testMethod void unitTest () {

        Test.setCurrentPageReference(new PageReference('Page.vf_BOG_Executive_Report'));
        vfCntrlr_BOG_Executive_Report controller = new vfCntrlr_BOG_Executive_Report();

        Test.StartTest();


        Test.StopTest();

    }
}
```

This is the controller

```
public class vfCntrlr_BOG_Executive_Report 
{

    //This next line allows this controller to pass data to the VF page vf_BOG_Committee_Report.vfp
    public String htmlCode { get; private set;} 
    public String reportName { get; private set;} 
    public String chairPerson1 { get; private set;}  
    public String chairPerson2 { get; private set;}  
    public String chairPerson3 { get; private set;}      


    public vfCntrlr_BOG_Executive_Report() 
    { 
        //Setup Query variables
        Id rcrdTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'BOG_Membership__c' AND Name = 'New BOG System' LIMIT 1].ID;

        String committeeName = '1 The Executive';
        String memStatus = 'Active';

        Decimal cntOrg=0; // so we can calculate the precentages of how many members per committee later on

        // Get all records from object     
        List<BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c> bogQueryList = [SELECT BOG_Committee__r.Name, BOG_Committee__r.Official_1__r.Name, BOG_Committee__r.Role_1__c,BOG_Committee__r.Official_2__r.Name, BOG_Committee__r.Role_2__c,BOG_Committee__r.Official_3__r.Name, BOG_Committee__r.Role_3__c, Member_Type__c, BOG_Membership__r.ORG__c,  Executive_Membership_Type__c, BOG_Membership__r.Contact_Name__c  
                                                            FROM BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c 
                                                            WHERE BOG_Committee__r.Name = : committeeName
                                                            AND BOG_Membership__r.BOG_Membership_Status__c = : memStatus
                                                            AND End_Date__c = Null
                                                            AND BOG_Membership__r.RecordTypeID = : rcrdTypeId
                                                            ORDER BY BOG_Membership__r.BOG_Committee_Report_Member_Order__c, BOG_Membership__r.BOG_Committee_Report_ORG_Order__c, BOG_Membership__r.Contact__r.LastName ];
        if(bogQueryList.size()>0)
        {
            Set <String> memTypes = New Set <String>(); // Unique list of membership types
            Set <String> orgs = New Set <String>(); // Unique list of orgs

            for(BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c record :bogQueryList) 
            { 
                reportName = record.BOG_Committee__r.Name;
                chairPerson1 = record.BOG_Committee__r.Official_1__r.Name + ' ' + record.BOG_Committee__r.Role_1__c;
                chairPerson2 = record.BOG_Committee__r.Official_2__r.Name + ' ' + record.BOG_Committee__r.Role_2__c;
                chairPerson3 = record.BOG_Committee__r.Official_3__r.Name + ' ' + record.BOG_Committee__r.Role_3__c;            

                // If these fields aren't poplulated leave as blank
                chairPerson1 = chairPerson1.replace('null', '');
                chairPerson2 = chairPerson2.replace('null', '');
                chairPerson3 = chairPerson3.replace('null', '');

                // Iterate through result set and populate the two membership and org lists
                if ((String) record.Executive_Membership_Type__c <> Null) memTypes.add((String) record.Executive_Membership_Type__c); 
                system.debug('debug mem ' + memTypes);
                if ((String) record.BOG_Membership__r.Org__c <> Null)orgs.add((String) record.BOG_Membership__r.ORG__c); 

                if((String) record.Executive_Membership_Type__c <>'Staff' && (String) record.Executive_Membership_Type__c <>'Invitee')   cntOrg++;//get total of how many members
            } 

            Integer cntNumMemberships=0;
            htmlCode =''; // The variable we return to the VF page
            String currContact = '';

            htmlCode = htmlCode + '<table>'; //wrap info in HTML table in a table to display properly
            Map<String,Integer> orgStats = new Map<String, Integer>();

            //Iterate through result set and put it in HTML table
            for(String mem : memTypes) 
            { 
                //          system.debug('This is the current membership ' + mem); 
                cntNumMemberships ++;// count how many per org
                htmlCode = htmlCode + '<tr><th>'+cntNumMemberships +'. '+mem+'</th></tr><tr>'; 

                if(mem <>'Staff' && mem <>'Invitee' && mem <>'Null')
                {    
                    for(String org : orgs) 
                    { 
                        // system.debug('This is the current org ' + org);

                        htmlCode = htmlCode + '<td><table><tr><th>' + org+'</th></tr>';    

                        //              system.debug('This is the htmlCode list ' + htmlCode); 
                        for(BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c record :bogQueryList) 
                        { 
                            currContact = (String) record.BOG_Membership__r.Contact_Name__c;
                            //                    system.debug('This is the currContact is ' + currContact); 
                            if((String) record.BOG_Membership__r.ORG__c == org && (String) record.Executive_Membership_Type__c == mem) 
                            { 
                                htmlCode = htmlCode + '<tr><td>'+currContact+'</td></tr>'; //put each contact on seperate line <td>                        

                                //Get get stats for report footer, make a map per org                        
                                if(!orgStats.containsKey(org))
                                {
                                    orgStats.put(org,1);
                                }
                                else
                                {   
                                    Integer tmp;
                                    tmp=orgStats.get(org);
                                    orgStats.put(org,tmp+1);
                                }

                            } 
                        }
                        htmlCode = htmlCode + '</table>';
                    } 
                }
                else if(mem =='Staff')
                {
                    for(BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c record :bogQueryList) 
                    { 
                        if((String) record.Executive_Membership_Type__c =='Staff')
                        {
                            currContact = (String) record.BOG_Membership__r.Contact_Name__c;
                            htmlCode = htmlCode + '<tr><td>'+currContact+'</td></tr>'; //put each contact on seperate line <td>                        
                        }

                    } 

                } else if(mem =='Invitee')
                {
                    for(BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c record :bogQueryList) 
                    { 
                        if((String) record.Executive_Membership_Type__c =='Invitee')
                        {
                            currContact = (String) record.BOG_Membership__r.Contact_Name__c;
                            htmlCode = htmlCode + '<tr><td>'+currContact+'</td></tr>'; //put each contact on seperate line <td>                        
                        }

                    } 

                }    



            } 
            htmlCode = htmlCode + '</table>'; 

            // Start generating stats for report footer        
            Decimal totals;
            Decimal stats;
            String statsOutput = '<br/><strong>Total Committee Members:</strong> ' + cntOrg.toPlainString();

            for(String org : orgs) 
            { 
                stats=orgStats.get(org);
                if (stats<>Null && cntOrg <> Null) totals = stats/cntOrg;//Divide current org by total of all members in any org
                if (stats<>Null) statsOutput = statsOutput + ' <b>' + org + '</b>:' + stats.setScale(0) + ' ' + totals.setScale(2) + '%';
            }   
            // Final output to VF Page
            htmlCode = htmlCode + statsOutput;
        } // if bogQueryList > 0 end bracket
        else
        {
            htmlCode = 'Sorry, there seems to be an issue generating this report. Please contact the project manager.';
        }
    } 

}
```

Comment: You might want to read up on unit testing (Pragmatic Unit Testing is a good series of books - the Java one fits well with Salesforce).  You seem to be missing some key concepts of unit testing - particularly the idea of using "asserts"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to run a test where bogQueryList would be <= 0.

In this case you are setting up 5 BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c objects in your testSetup so they will always exists.

You can either:

- Move the setup of those objects into the test method itself and create a second test method that does not create them. (Recommended)
- Or Create a new test class where you do not create the
  BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c records

Comment: Which is the better design?

Comment: Considering you need to capture both I would have 1 class with multiple methods. The methods would define the data needed to get the expected result.

Comment: Before you answered I made a second test class. When I check my code coverage I see 98% for my first test class and 15% for the second. Am I done and I can deploy my code or must one say 100%.

Comment: Are all lines covered over both? You don't need one class to cover something 100%, as long as you are testing all possible outcomes. Also, as @Rob Baillie alludes to - you shouldn't be creating tests purely for code coverage, your tests should assert your functionality as well - however that is probably a different topic.

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie. Can you give me concrete example(s) in this specific case as to what I should be asserting? I keep hearing this but I don't really get it. How many things must I assert? Also, is there anything else that needs improving in this test class?

Comment: BTW, yes, between the two test classes all lines are covered.

Comment: That's a much broader question then I have time/space to answer in a comment. In general what you need to do is look at your method and ask yourself 'What is this supposed to do?'. What are the expected results based on the data available? In this case if no records of a certain type exist then you would expect htmlCode to be set to your Error Message - your test should reflect that by using System.assert() or System.assertEquals(). You also want to test for positive results as well, what do you expect to happen when the data does exist? Assert that in your positive test.